# 22.04 audio input/output and volume control issues

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I recently started over with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, after having some issues with updating to 23.04, as both 22.10 and 23.04 come with pipewire by default, which my sound card does not play nice with.

In the past, I have always had to run a bash script, found [here](https://pastebin.com/6uVzPjCb), in order to have the sound card work properly, with the selected output corresponding with the actual method, but this time the script is not working properly. Currently, in order to have sound come from my laptop speakers I need to have the headphones output selected, and there is no way for my headphones jack to output sound, with either the headphones or standard output ( selected. My laptop microphone doesn't work (as far as I can tell, it is physically broken; I don't expect to fix it), so having a non-working headphones jack causes me significant problems apart from having a non-standard but otherwise working solution to use the headphones jack to output speaker sound.

Simultaneously, the volume increase/decrease is behaving peculiarly, as changing the volume only works for the first 10%, and then it is at maximum volume, with 5% being at half volume. It seems to me that every 1% increase or decrease in volume is actually acting as a 10% increase in volume.

Can anyone suggest something so I can have working headphones and a working volume control? Help is much appreciated.

alsamixer reports the card as "Card: sof-glkda7219max" and the chip as "Chip: Intel Geminilake HDMI"

edit: to be clear, on my old installation, which was 22.10, after removing pipewire and reverting to pulseaudio I had no issues so long as I had run the attached bash script at least once with super user permissions.